# Recieving Error "no more data from to read from socket" when using trigger

Tags: oracle, sockets, plsql, triggers

I created a table that is used for tracking the creation of tables in the schema but when the trigger compiles it is throwing an error "no more data from socket" and I lose connection to the database.

My audit table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_AUDIT(
DATE_CREATED DATE,
USERNAME VARCHAR2(30),
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30))
```

And my trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER tableCreationTrigger
AFTER CREATE 
   ON SCHEMA    
DECLARE  
  date_created TABLE_AUDIT.DATE_CREATED%type;  
  username TABLE_AUDIT.USERNAME%type;
  table_name TABLE_AUDIT.TABLE_NAME%type;
BEGIN
date_created := sysdate;
SELECT USER
into username
from dual;
:New.table_Name := table_name;

INSERT INTO TABLE_AUDIT (DATE_CREATED, USERNAME, TABLE_NAME)
Values(DATE_CREATED, USERNAME, TABLE_NAME);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN others THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error on insert into table_audit');  
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to restart the DB and try again .

"no more data from socket" is due to DB is not able to respond to the query.